# spring integration kafka - DSL KafkaListener message payload deserialised to incorrect object type

Tags: spring-integration, spring-kafka

Spring integration Kafka Listener (DSL) which consumes messages from Kafka topic and de-serializes message payload to JSON POJO object. The consumer is configured correctly to receive an Object type of A. But when the message is consumed, the spring integration kafka topic listener,  it is de-serialized  as  type B object. Most of the fields in The object A and Object B are same except for  few  fields.

When I consume the message on the kafka topic using console consumer tool   it correctly consumes the message as  as type B the object type and shows  all the fields.

Please find the version and broker details below.

```
springKafkaVersion =  2.1.5.RELEASE
springIntegrationVersion = 2.0.3.RELEASE
springIntegrationKafkaVersion = 3.0.3.RELEASE
kakfa client 1.0.1
```

Comment: You need to show your configuration.

Comment: It can't be `springIntegrationVersion = 2.0.3.RELEASE` though. You need to rely on the transitive version from the `springIntegrationKafkaVersion = 3.0.3.RELEASE`